# How to replace entire string with Regex capture groups in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

In a NodeJS application, I have a phone number field in my data that displays any number of phone numbers, one after another, in the same string:

`\n\n  \n  (555) 555-5555 (Main)\n\n, \n\n  \n  (777) 777-777 (Domestic Fax)\n\n`

I want to extract only the 'Main' phone number and convert it to the format `555-555-5555`, that is whatever the Main number is. Basically I just want to extract whatever number precedes 'Main' and make it more legible (replacing the space with the '-')

I got as far as finding the correct regex string

`const phoneRegex = /^[ \\n]*\(([0-9]{3})\)( )([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}) \(Main\).*$/`

but when I try to replace the string, it doesn't work

`foo.phone =foo.phone.replace(phoneRegex,'$1-$3')`

I keep getting the entire matched portion -- that is all the \n's and everything up to and including '(Main)'

I have searched for how to replace the entire string with the capture groups, but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: Look beyond `replace` – you can extract a match first (see `RegExp#exec` or `String#match`), then create a new string from that.

Comment: Try `s.replace(/^\s*\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d+)-(\d+)[^]*$/, '$1-$2-$3')`, I believe the `\n` are the newline chars in your sample string (you must have copied/pasted the string literal value from the console rather than shared the literal text).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew -- The \n characters actually come in the data returned -- I'm not sure how that would change the regex you provided

Comment: Change `^\s*` with `^[^]*?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew -- I'm afraid that didn't work.  I keep getting the entire matched portion -- that is all the \n's and everything up to and including '(Main)'

Comment: It works, see my answer below with explanation and demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
var s = "\\n\\n  \\n  (555) 555-5555 (Main)\\n\\n, \\n\\n  \\n  (777) 777-777 (Domestic Fax)\\n\\n";
console.log(
  s.replace(/^[^]*?\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d+)-(\d+)\s*\(Main\)[^]*/, '$1-$2-$3')
);
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^]*?` - any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `\(` - a `(`
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1: three digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(Main\)` - a `(Main)` string
- `[^]*` - the rest of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4oaYAf/1).

Comment: Perfect!  Indeed, I was using Regex101.com to build my original string.  It was cruder and less efficient than yours, but it seemed to match.  I wonder why it wasn't replacing the entire matched string correctly.  In any case, I'll review your answer.

Comment: @Cerulean I still think your string contains newlines and not ``\`` + `n` char combinations, and your `\n`s are actually `"\n"`s. `.` does not match newlines and carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

Would that work for you?

```js
const str = `\n\n  \n  (555) 555-5555 (Main)\n\n, \n\n  \n  (777) 777-777 (Domestic Fax)\n\n`,

      [,code, phone] = str.match(/\((\d{3})\)\s(\d{3}\-\d{4})\s\(Main\)/),
      result = `${code}-${phone}`
      
console.log(result)
```

Comment: My bad -- I didn't want the 714 in the final result.  (The 714 is from the actual data -- I was trying to make it more general with '555').  Basically I just want to extract whatever number precedes 'Main' and make it more legible (replacing the space with the '-')

Comment: @Cerulean : like that one?